# i am trying css to half half dot red and half colored but unable to get it

Tags: css

i have the css where i was able to get the dots for colors for css.

now i am trying to half half colors for some dots and not all, but my css is not working well. here is my css for the full dots

trying like this

https://prnt.sc/DJ4EuunidNtA

```css
  

.holder {
     margin-right: 5px;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .h1 {
    background: blue;
    }

    .h2 {
    background: red;
    }

    .h3 {
    background: green;
    }



    .h4 {
    background: grey;
    }



    .h5 {
    background: yellow;
    }



    .displayData th {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    min-width: 30px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:start;
    margin:10px;
    }



    .displayData td {
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background:none;
    }
```

```html
<table class="displayData">
<tr>
  <th>
   Drafted
  </th>
  <th>
   Submitted
  </th>
  <th>
   Approved
  </th>
  <th>
   Processed
  </th>
</tr>

  <tr>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       No
    </td>
   </cfif>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h5">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Drafted    
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Submitted approved   
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Approved   
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Processed    
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h5">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h2">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Rejected - draft   
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
    Rejected 
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

the html and the css code how the functionality is going to work

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your code there is no HTML (are the headers the dots?), definition of size, or an attempt to make only half of the dot colored

Comment: sorry, yes, i will update the code

Comment: Where is the CSS for the dots - there just isn't any that I can see.

Comment: that is all i have and it shows the dots,

Comment: i updated the missing section of the css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient()`:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right ,green 50%, gray 50%);
```

```css
.holder {
     margin-right: 5px;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .h1 {
    background: blue;
    }

    .h2 {
    background: red;
    }

    .h3 {
    background: green;
    }
    



    .h4 {
    background: grey;
    }



    .h5 {
    background: yellow;
    }
    .h6{
      background: linear-gradient(to right ,green 50%, gray 50%);
    }



    .displayData th {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    min-width: 30px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:start;
    margin:10px;
    }



    .displayData td {
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background:none;
    }
```

```html
<table class="displayData">
<tr>
  <th>
   Drafted
  </th>
  <th>
   Submitted
  </th>
  <th>
   Approved
  </th>
  <th>
   Processed
  </th>
</tr>

  <tr>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h6">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       No
    </td>
   </cfif>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h5">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Drafted    
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Submitted approved   
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Approved   
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Processed    
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h5">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h2">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
       Rejected - draft   
    </td>

    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h3">
       <div/>
    </td>
    <td>
       <div class="holder h4">
       <div/>
    </td>

    <td>
    Rejected 
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```